# In VSO release Powershell task is failing while using 'Azure Pipelines' agent and same task is passing while using 'Hosted MSIT Fortify 2017' agent

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, release

Normal VSO release should work with the 'Azure Pipelines' agent. But it is failing  in Azure Powershell task saying 'Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts'.. While same task is running with the 'Fortify' agent

Tried all possible agents other than 'Fortify'. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your script?

Comment: @Kaustubh How is it going with this case, Any update?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with version 4 of the task. I switched to 3 and it got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar error using task Azure Powershell "`Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: '5.1.1' If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure Pipelines task agent"`.

My fix to this error is to use the latest version of `azurePowerShellVersion`,

```
azurePowerShellVersion: 'latestVersion'
```

For classic view:

select the latest version 4.* of task **Azure Powershell**

[image]

check **latest installed verison** for **azure powershell version**

[image]

If above fix does not work for you. For better troubleshooting, please post the full error message and the detailed settings of Azure Powershell task.

Comment: I tried with 'latest version' option for VSO powershell release task. Didn't work for me.. throwing similar error : 'Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: ''. If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the Azure Pipelines task agent.'

Comment: The error of yours may indicate the version is not correctly specified.Could you please share a screen shot of your detailed settings of Azure Powershell task?

Comment: Please also use the latest version `Azure Pipelines task`  version 4.*. I updated my answer